# Recursive Fibonacci Sequence from C Code to MIPS

Tags: recursion, stack, mips

Hi I am trying to rewrite the fib function from Problem 2 on: **https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/sp15/hw/03/CS61C_Homework3Soln.pdf**

to understand the code better and it seems to give me an infinite loop somewhere.

I tried to trace the stack by hand but it is very confusing at the moment since I am not too sure where the error happens. I tried to debug using QtSpim but that does not work

My fib is called recursively:

```
fib:
li $t4,1 # to compare 1 with other registers
sub $sp , $sp , 12
sw $ra , 0($sp) 
sw $t0 , 4($sp)
sw $t1 , 8($sp)

move $t1, $a0   #load n from a0 to t1

beq $t1 , $zero , Returnzero 
move $t0, $v0
beq $t1, $t4, Returnone

addi $a0, $t1 , −1

jal fib # compute fib(n-1)

move $t3 , $v0 # store return value of fib(n-1)

lw $a0 , 4 ($sp)

addi $a0, $t1, −2 # n-2

jal fib # compute fib(n-2)

add $v0, $v0, $t3 # sum of fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

# restore stack here
lw $t1, 8($sp)
lw $t3, 4($sp)
lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 12 

jr $ra


lw $s0, 8($sp)
lw $ra, 0($sp)

Returnzero:
move $v0, $zero #if 0 go return 0
jr $ra

Returnone:
move $v0, $s0 #if 1 go return 1
jr $ra
```

Comment: Doesn't `li` need an immediate value to load?

Comment: QtSpim does debugging, so perhaps you can work that a bit harder. If you don't like it you can also use MARS instead. You definitely need to single step to find your errors. `fib(2)` should be enough to find them.  This Q&A website is not the best forum for interactive debugging.  For that you might try a mentoring site like [codementor.io](https://www.codementor.io/erikeidt) -- you can get help with both learning how to debug as well as finding the errors in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst mistake is here:

```
    ...
    jr $ra          # <--- this is an unconditional branch; it won't come back


    lw $s0, 8($sp)  # <--- this code will never execute: it is what we call "dead" code
    lw $ra, 0($sp)

Returnzero:
    move $v0, $zero #if 0 go return 0
    jr $ra

Returnone:
    move $v0, $s0 #if 1 go return 1
    jr $ra
```

Any code between an unconditional branch and a label is "dead", it can never be reached! <sub>(this is a slight oversimplification but generally accurate and very appropriate here)</sub>  So that code is obviously not helping you.

As a result, you are returning in some cases without running the epilogue code, which undoes the prologue, and, this undoing is absolutely required, as you know.

To be clear, the epilogue code in the case of return 1 and return 0 are both lacking and need to reflect undoing of the full prologue sequence.

---

Fundamentally, your registers usages are a bit messed up.

You're storing `$t0` and `$t1` into the stack, but there's nothing in them the first go.  Later you're using what was stored from `$t0` as if there was something meaningful in it (there isn't).  I suspect what you want to be storing here are `$a0`, and `$s0` — though each for different reasons.